# Ruby on Rails Search Bar for Devise Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

hey guys im working on an application where there a two devise users 'Family' & 'Team', I want one of the users to be able to search for the other users by name. I'm having trouble doing this i currently have the following code

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable

  def self.search(user_name)
    if user_name
      user_name.downcase!
      where('LOWER(name) LIKE ?', "%#{user_name}%")
    else
      all
    end
  end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :teams, path: 'teams' , controllers: { sessions: "teams/sessions", confirmations: 'teams/confirmations', registrations: 'teams/registrations'}
```

**controller.rb**

```
def team_search
  @users = Team.search(params[:search])      
end
```

**view**

```
<%= form_tag teams_path, :method => 'get' do %>
   <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is you problem exactly? Could you tell us what you get and what you want? Or maybe you have an error message and stacktrace? Give it to us :)

Comment: @mrzasa thanks for the quick reply im having trouble on what url to use for the get request here 

        <%= form_tag "im having trouble using the right URL here ", :method => 'get' 
      do %>

Comment: i dont really know what URL to use here since i am using devise

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate controller and path:

```
class TeamsController
  def search
    # ...
  end
end

# routes.rb
resources :team do
  collection do 
    get :search
  end 
end
```